# Asp.net url rewriting and domain redirection

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, dns, redirect

I have a domain "test.com" and I want this domain to redirect to "mydomain.com/test". I'm with 1and1 for my domain test.com and with discountAsp for mydomain.com.

In the control panel of 1and1 you can set a redirection from a domain to another domain, so everything is fine.

But when i'm on the page mydomain.com/test I want my url to be rewritten as test.com

Is this possible to do that with IIS or in my asp.page (would prefer in my page)

I'm using iis7
Thanks

Comment: Do you use IIS7? and your ASP.net version?

Comment: if you are using IIS7 and asp.net 3.5+ try asp.net routing or else search and find  Urlrewriting dll and set url redirect/routing rules in web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that, maybe you could use an iframe so from *test.com* you open an iframe containing web content hosted in *mydomain.com/test*, the visitor is seeing *test.com* but content is actually hosted in *mydomain.com*.

Comment: Not sure how the Search engine react to this ?

Comment: Don't know either, one trick seo guys do is put some text in hidden divs (or pop-ups that never get pop-upped), but maybe that's entering muddy lands...